# Is it possible to exclude some elements from parsing when using regular expression and .replace()?

Tags: jquery, regex

```
<script language="javascript">
    $("div.post-content , .parsedsig").each(function(){
        if($(this).html().indexOf("[/tabulaScriptum]") != -1) {
             pattern = /\[tabulaScriptum=(.*?)\]([^\[]*)\[\/tabulaScriptum\]/gi
             $(this).html($(this).html().replace(pattern, "<div class='tabulaScriptum'><div class='tabulaNomen'>$1</div><div class='tabulaImpleo'>$2</div></div>")) 
        }
    });
</script>
```

This script is working perfectly, except for one thing... I need not to replace `[tabulaScriptum=][/tabulaScriptum]` in certain elements. For example, I don't want to replace those "tags" in element that has class .code-box. Is it possible?

Clarification: element .code-box is located within .post-content.

Clarification #2: this script creates simple division spoiler. `.tabulaScriptum` is spoier's body, `.tabulaNomen` is spoiler's name and button which, in turn, reveals(or hides) `.tabulaImpleo` on click. Reveal\hide script is located in some other place, and I didn't post it here since it doesn't really matter.

Clarification #3: http://jsfiddle.net/PRtsw/1/ fiddle.

Comment: please post some example code

Comment: Why don't you post a fiddle that has as much of what you're trying to get working in place as possible with some sample content?

Comment: Updated question with fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. The first one that springs to mind is to use jQuery's `.not(selector)` method.

http://jsfiddle.net/nate/2hNEA/

> $("div.post-content, .parsedsig").not('.code-box').each(function () {
>   ...
>   });

**Update #1**

The clarification that `.code-box` was a child of `.post-content` came after I submitted this answer. That makes the problem a lot more interesting! I'd be interested to see how wiser heads than mine deal with this.

One solution that occurs to me is to take a two-pass approach.

First make your change just as you have implemented it, then go back and reverse the substition for `.code-box` divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/nate/2hNEA/1/

```
$("div.post-content .code-box .tabulaScriptum").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.before('[tabulaScriptum=]' + $this.text() + '[/tabulascriptum]');
    $this.remove();
});
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but it seems to work.

**Update #2:**

Here's another, simpler way:

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/nate/2hNEA/2/

Just render the tabulaScriptum text inside any `.code-box` elements unrecognizable before doing your larger search/replace. Once you've finished, restore them.

```
// Temporarily render .code-box contained tabulas unrecognizable
$('.code-box').each(function () {
    var pattern = /\[tabula/gi;
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(pattern, "[placeholder"));
});

// Search / Replace, as before...

// Restore .code-box contained tabulas
$('.code-box').each(function () {
    var pattern = /\[placeholder/gi;
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(pattern, "[tabula"));
});​
```

**Update #3:**

Thanks for including a fiddle! Here's your example with my last solution in place.

http://jsfiddle.net/nate/PRtsw/2/

Comment: Just saw your clarification edit - that makes the problem a bit more complicated. I'll update in a minute or two.

Comment: Np) It's not like I'm going anywhere.

Comment: My main problem is that this script creates a working spoiler which works by clicking `<div class="tabulaNomen">some text</div>`. After click event `<div class="tabulaImpleo"></div>` reveals itself. Division with `.tabulaNomen` class holds name of the spoiler which comes after `=` sign in `[tabulaScriptum=]` tag. So if I'm going to decompose my spoiled I'll need to break each component individualy. `.tabulaScriptum`, which holds the whole spoiler, `.tabulaNomen` which holds its name and, finaly, `.tabulaImpleo`, which holds html within the spoiler.

Comment: Sounds like you should provide some more context to your question. (I don't blame you for trying to simplify, initially.) Could you post a fiddle, please?

Comment: I just added a simpler solution - just mangle the [tabulaScriptum] tags inside your .code-box elements first, then restore them after the search/replace.